# ¿Como mostrar una lista de datos obtenidos de Firebase en React?

Tags: base-de-datos, reactjs, firebase, map, crud

Estoy realizando un ejercicio de aplicacion web, un  CRUD en React utilizando Hook y Firebase. Logre realizar el registro y  mostrar su contenido en la consola. Pero necesito mostrar una lista de su contenido. ¿Como puedo realizar una lista con un map(), que me muestre el valor de "Codigo" y "Formula"?. He probado diferentes formas y no he tenido exito.

[Imagen de la DB en Firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbSH7.png)

```js
const firebase= useFirebaseApp();

function mostrarnewformula(){
const database = firebase.database();
var ref = database.ref(`/formula`);
ref.once("value").then(function(snapshot) {
   snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
     var key = childSnapshot.key;
     var childData = childSnapshot.val();
     console.log(key);
     console.log(childData)
   }); 
 
  });  return (  <div><p>Lista:  </p><li></li></div>)
}

return(
<Fragment>
<div className="container">
    MOSTRAR:{mostrarnewformula()}
</div>
</Fragment>
)

}
```

Comment: Algún error particular? Trae tus datos? No los trae?

Comment: En esa operación me muestra los datos en la consola, pero no he logrado con éxito mostrarlos en una lista.